# How do I reimport e-mails of the last few days only from Gmail into Thunderbird?

Tags: gmail, pop3, gmail-archive, thunderbird

After a complete reinstall, I am glad to see that all my settings and e-mails archives are safe in my `~/.thunderbird` backup.

However, a few days passed between my last `~/.thunderbird` backup and the day of my system's crash. So I miss a few processed, but non-backed-up e-mails from this period.

How do I POP3 them again into Thunderbird without downloading *all* Gmail archives again?